# How to solve the xpath issue of appium in marshmallow devices?

Tags: xpath, appium, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to automate an app . I have found few of the elements using xpath. In marshmallow devices, the elements are not able to find using xpath which is working fine in kitkat/lollipop devices. For example in **KitKat/lollipop** the **xpath** contains **view**; the same xpath in **marshmallow instead of view it is taking as Viewgroup**. How to provide the same xpath for all the version?

The following are  the xpath of the same element in kitkat and marshmallow :

**In kitkat: xPath is** //android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[‌​1]/android.widget.Fr‌​ameLayout[1]/android‌​.view.View[1]/androi‌​d.view.View[1]/andro‌​id.view.View[1]/andr‌​oid.view.View[1]/and‌​roid.view.View[1]/an‌​droid.support.v4.wid‌​get.DrawerLayout[1]/‌​android.view.View[1]‌​/android.view.View[2‌​]/android.widget.Scr‌​ollView[1]/android.v‌​iew.View[1]/android.‌​widget.ScrollView[1]‌​/android.view.View[1‌​]/android.view.View[‌​1]

**In Marshmallow: (for same element xpath is as below)** //android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[‌​1]/android.widget.Fr‌​ameLayout[1]/android‌​.view.ViewGroup[1]/a‌​ndroid.view.ViewGrou‌​p[1]/android.view.Vi‌​ewGroup[1]/android.v‌​iew.ViewGroup[1]/and‌​roid.view.ViewGroup[‌​1]/android.support.v‌​4.widget.DrawerLayou‌​t[1]/android.view.Vi‌​ewGroup[1]/android.v‌​iew.ViewGroup[2]/and‌​roid.widget.ScrollVi‌​ew[1]/android.view.V‌​iewGroup[1]/android.‌​widget.ScrollView[1]‌​/android.view.ViewGr‌​oup[1]/android.view.‌​ViewGroup[1]

Comment: can you post a piece of code for reference?

Comment: In kitkat: xPath is //android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]

Comment: In Marshmallow: (for same element xpath is as below)                                                                                              //android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]

Comment: Edit the question with the xpath plz.

Answer (score 0):

If you use RELATIVE XPATH your xpath will work for all OS versions.

You are using **Absolute xpath** which is very bad practice. It is always recommended to use **Relative xpath**.

You can read more about relative and absolute xpaths [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183353/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-and-relative-xpaths-which-is-preferred)