# What does dot(.) mean in the xpath of selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath

What is the difference between the functionality of

`.//input[@id='stack']` and `//input[@id='stack']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between absolute and relative xpaths? Which is preferred in Selenium automation testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183353/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-and-relative-xpaths-which-is-preferred)

Answer (score 9):

`.` always represents the current element. So your first statement looks for all `<input id='stack'>` beneath the actual element while the latter globally looks for all input elements with the id 'stack'.