# AngularJs page issue with selecting an element and clicking it

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

I have a problem with selecting and clicking an element it so the drop down occurs here is what i have tried uptill now:-

```js
String csspath = "html body.ng-scope f:view form#wdesk.ng-pristine.ng-valid div.container div.ng-scope md-content.md-padding._md md-tabs.ng-isolate-scope.md-dynamic-height md-tabs-content-wrapper._md md-tab-content#tab-content-7._md.ng-scope.md-active.md-no-scroll div.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope ng-include.ng-scope div.ng-scope accordion div.accordion div.accordion-group.ng-isolate-scope div.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle.ng-binding span.ng-scope b.ng-binding";
String uxpath = "//html//body//f:view//form//div//div[2]//md-content//md-tabs//md-tabs-content-wrapper//md-tab-content[1]//div//ng-include//div//accordion//div//div[1]//div[1]//a";
String xpath2 = "/html/body/pre/span[202]/a";
xpath = "/html/body/f:view/form/div/div[2]/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[1]/div/ng-include/div/accordion/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/span/b";
try {
  element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(csspath)));

  locator = By.cssSelector(csspath);
  driver.findElement(locator).click();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Not foune csspath");
}



try {
  element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));

  locator = By.xpath(xpath);
  driver.findElement(locator).click();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Not foune xpath");
}

try {
  element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(uxpath)));

  locator = By.xpath(uxpath);
  driver.findElement(locator).click();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Not foune uxpath");
}

try {
  element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath2)));

  locator = By.xpath(xpath2);
  driver.findElement(locator).click();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Not foune xpath2");
}
```

However nothing has worked till now i want to select responsibility code and give it values

It would be really appreciated if you can give me any insight 
Thanks in advance
Here is a screenshot of my issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0CT2.png)

Comment: Can you paste the HTML DOM properly in the Question with some more relevant HTML tags?

Comment: Really sorry but i cant as i dont have enough reputation yet

Comment: okay, if the url you are using is public would you be able to share the url with me?

Comment: all your xpath is really long, google about how to find good xpath and css. it should be shot and should be able to uniquely find the element.  Use the tool like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firepath/ to check if you XPath is valid or not.

Comment: url i am using is not public

Comment: i used the firebug path earlier and it was this long and worked

Answer (score 0):

First issue (as already pointed out in comments) is the absolute selectors you are using. For example, try to refactor your xpath selectors and make those [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183353/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-and-relative-xpaths-which-is-preferred).

Next issue is related to the

> AngularJs page

itself. Let's look at [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/), the testing framework for Angular built upon WebDriverJS, it provides additional WebDriver-like functionality to test Angular based websites. Put simple - your code needs extra functionality that will know when Angular elements are available for interaction.

Here is [how to port](https://github.com/emanlove/SeConf2015/blob/master/SeConf2015_EdManlove_Dealertrack.pdf) some of the most useful Protractor functions to Java (and Python):

[image]