# Is it okay to use such xpath to find web elements?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Consider this xpath which should always return one element.

```
//div[@id='MyDiv123']/div[contains(@class, 'super')]
```

Assume that we won't add anymore divs whose class is super. Given that info, I don't think  that it is a good idea to use `/div[contains(@class, 'super')]`because the xpath will break if `div[contains(@class, 'super')]` is placed inside another element.

Shouldn't we be using `//div[contains(@class, 'super')]` instead ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't like using XPaths for locators that can be written as a CSS selector. I think it's much simpler as

```
#MyDiv123 > div.super
```

or just

```
div.super
```

if it's unique on the page.

XPath `contains()` is a string match. All the elements below will match your XPath locator but none of them will match the CSS selectors above.

```
<div class="super-duper" ...>
<div class="superior" ...>
<div class="abcsuperdef" ...>
```

... you get the idea...

Comment: Amazingly, you have commented against my code `div[@class='super']` with _By hard coding =, you've guaranteed that any additional class on that DIV will break the locator_. How is the first line from your Answer `div.super` different?

Comment: Because `div.super` isn't a string match, it's a class name match.

Comment: Well, for your reference _xpath_ as `div[@class='super']` is exactly equivalent to _css_ as `div.super`. Please refer the [XPath Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/).

Comment: But wait, how does the **CSS selector** comes into discussion here? Doesn't the question heading clearly mentions about **xpath to find web elements**

Comment: `<div class="super duper">`... do both locators find that element?

Comment: CS selectors come into play because OP is looking for a more simple way to find the same element. I'm explaining that XPath, in this case, has issues that CSS selectors do not.

Comment: @JeffC - I agree with your answer. CSS is indeed the simpler approach here. Btw, I was wondering what a xpath version of your css selector would look like - #MyDiv123 > div.super.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I tried div[@class='super'] on sample code and found that it is not the same as div.super. As JeffC said, it will break if more classes are added.

Comment: @testerjoe2 The closest match with XPath is basically what you already had. It just has more drawbacks than the CSS selector version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined *Best Practices* while writing *xpaths*. It all boils down to how effective *xpath* can be written.

I don't see any issue with the *xpath* as :

```
//div[@id='MyDiv123']/div[contains(@class, 'super')]
```

Of-coarse there ca be some improvements as follows :

- As an enduser you won't be sure how the *class* attribute **super** impacts the *HTML* or which elements have this attribute. So in that case to identify the *WebElement* uniquely it would be wise to include the ancestor `<div>` tag with *id* as **MyDiv123**.
- But it doesn't looks like the *classname* **super** can be dynamic. Hence you can avoid the keyword *contains* within the *xpath* and rewrite it as :

  ```
  //div[@id='MyDiv123']/div[@class='super']
  ```

Comment: OP can determine if the locator will identify the element uniquely and would be in the best position to determine if the ID is needed. Also, how can you tell if the class `super` is or isn't dynamic given the lack of HTML provided? By hard coding `=`, you've guaranteed that any additional class on that `DIV` will break the locator.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for your comments. As you mentioned `OP ... would be in the best position to determine` why not to leave it upto OP to take the call? My Answer is just a way to address OP's question may/may-not suffice OP's need. Feel free to pour in your ideas through a well researched Answer.

Comment: I agree that OP should make the call... that's why I'm confused as to why you are making the call here: `it would be wise to include the ancestor <div> tag` and here: `Hence you can avoid the keyword contains within the xpath and rewrite it as`.