# Selenium find element by class name two parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How do I find elements by class name without repeating the output? I have two class to scrape `hdrlnk` and `results-price`. I wrote the code like this:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(['hdrlnk','result-price'])
```

and it gives me some error. I have another code that I tried and here it is:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hdrlnk'),
y = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-price')
for xs in x:
    for ys in y:
        print(xs.text + ys.text)
```

But I got the result like this

```
sony 5 disc cd changer$40
sony 5 disc cd changer$70
sony 5 disc cd changer$70
sony 5 disc cd changer$190
sony 5 disc cd changer$190
sony 5 disc cd changer$190
sony 5 disc cd changer$190
sony 5 disc cd changer$10
```

The part of the HTML structure that I am trying to scrape

```
<p class="result-info">
    <span class="icon icon-star" role="button" title="save this post in your favorites list">
        <span class="screen-reader-text">favorite this post</span>
    </span>
    <time class="result-date" datetime="2019-11-07 18:20" title="Thu 07 Nov 06:20:56 PM">Nov  7</time>
    <a href="https://vancouver.craigslist.org/rch/ele/d/chandeliers/7015824686.html" data-id="7015824686" class="result-title hdrlnk">CHANDELIERS</a>
    <span class="result-meta">
        <span class="result-price">$800</span>
        <span class="result-hood"> (Richmond)</span>
        <span class="result-tags">
            <span class="pictag">pic</span>
        </span>
        <span class="banish icon icon-trash" role="button">
            <span class="screen-reader-text">hide this posting</span>
        </span>
        <span class="unbanish icon icon-trash red" role="button" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <a href="#" class="restore-link">
            <span class="restore-narrow-text">restore</span>
            <span class="restore-wide-text">restore this posting</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</p>
```

The first element is repeated but I got the correct value for the second one. How do I correct this error?

Comment: Can you add the HTML code you are trying to scrape?

Comment: Ok sir wait a bit

Comment: Does the HTML have many of these `<p class="result-info">` elements? And each of them contains a `hdrlnk` and a `result-price`?

Comment: yes sir. youre right @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @Vince See two options in my answer below.

Comment: ok sir i will try it and tell you the results in a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need `nested loop`, try your iteration by object length, utilize `len` method:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hdrlnk'),
#y = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-price')
y = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]/span[@class="result-meta"]//span[@class="result-price"]')

print(len(x))
print(len(y))

for i in range(len(x)) :
    print(x[i].text + y[i].text)
```

**UPDATE**

Actually I just imagine you want to couple member `x` with member `y`, it will looks like this:

```
x[0] with y[0]
x[1] with y[1]
etc....
```

So I'm sure you having same number between `x` and `y`. Because of that reason I think, I just need `x` to represent `loop` (although, also you can use `y` instead).

If you want to include both of them in the `loop`, you can use `zip`. Please learn from other answers in this thread.

For `xpath` you can see here: [`Locator Strategies`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

With copy `xpath` from inspect element it will give you absolute path.  I don't recommend it, because it is very vulnerable to change.

Please see this thread: [`Absolute vs Relative Xpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183353/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-and-relative-xpaths-which-is-preferred)

Comment: It works for me sir. Thanks a lot. Could you explain to me deeper why you only use `x` in the len loop. And why does the answers below doesn't work for me?

Comment: Ohw sir it has some drawbacks in it. It kinda works but the price is repeated twice befor it is updated. Its like this

`ipad (6th gen) 32gb wifi+cellular BNIB , $425
drag 2 platinum with smok tfv12 tank , $425
Brand New Lightning Cable , $100`

drag 2 platinum price was getting the price of the ipad which is $425 instead of $100.

Comment: @Vince With the above code, I assume you have same number of `x` and `y`. So if you facing repeated twice `price`, it possible you have `y` more than `x`. I've updated the code, please try again and how did it go, I've changed the locator by `xpath` and for make it will print the length of both lists first.

Comment: Now this works for me. But I have a question, why did you used `xpath` instead of classname? And in your loop statement why you only used `x` variable and not `y` Im a little bit confused of it

Comment: how did you come up with that xpath sir? I tried copying the xpath from inspect element and it get me an xpath like this `//*[@id="sortable-results"]/ul/li[1]/p/span[2]/span[1]`

Comment: @Vince I've added a bit explanation in the answer, please see. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

`.find_elements_by_class_name()` only takes a single class name. What I would suggest is using a CSS selector to do this job, e.g. `.hdrlnk .result-price`. The code would look like

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.hdrlnk .result-price')
```

This prints all the prices. If you also want the labels, you will have to write a little more code.

```
for heading in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.hdrlnk'):
    print(heading.text)
    for price in heading.find_elements_by_xpath('./following::span[@class="result-price"]'):
        print('  ' + price.text)
```

See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for all the options to find elements.

CSS selector references:
[W3C reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)
[Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)
[Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

Comment: I second this approach.

Comment: `x` here is a little challenging to iterate over since you need to take two elements at a time. I'm not saying it can't be done, but it requires some tricks from the itertools recipes.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah I posted the answer and then went back and reread the question and realized from what OP was printing he might want something other than what I thought based on his original locators. I've since updated my answer to also include this second approach.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have elements with classes `hdrlnk` and `result-price` that come in pairs. So you need to iterate the lists in parallel with `zip()`:

```py
xs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hdrlnk'),
ys = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-price')
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    print(x.text, y.text)
```

This assumes that the two lists contain the same number of elements in the correct order so that they match up correctly with `zip()`. It is probably safer to parse them directly from the HTML by iterating over the parent `<p>` elements:

```py
ps = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-info')
for p in ps:
    x = p.find_element_by_class_name('hdrlnk'),
    y = p.find_element_by_class_name('result-price')
    print(x.text, y.text)
```

Comment: I tried the first one and got me an errof of `'list' object has no attribute 'text'` the error is in the `print(x.text, y.text)`. I tried to modify it by `print(xs.text, ys.text)` And got an error of `"message": "Instance of 'tuple' has no 'text' member"`

Comment: The second one got also an error of `'tuple' object has no attribute 'text'` And in my terminal I got output like this 
`[15768:7180:1108/132750.647:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(166)] Invalid first_paint 2.392 s for first_image_paint 2.388 s`. What should I do sir?

Comment: @Vince You appear to be doing something slightly different than what I have here. I don't see how the code I gave can give any of those errors.

Comment: @Vince If you need more help, post a new question with your current code and its errors.

Comment: @Vince I found a mistake in my second example. I don't think the change affects the errors you are seeing, but it does fix a logic error.

Answer (score 1):

If your usecase is to use `find_elements_by _classname()` a better approach would be to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CLASS_NAME`:

  ```
  items = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "hdrlnk")))
  prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "result-price")))
  for i,j in zip(items, prices):
      print(i.text + j.text)
  ```

However a canonical approach will be to use either of the following:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  items = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.result-info a.hdrlnk")))
  prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.result-info span.result-meta>span.result-price")))
  for i,j in zip(items, prices):
      print(i.text + j.text)
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  items = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='result-info']//a[contains(@class, 'hdrlnk')]")))
  items = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='result-info']//span[@class='result-meta']/span[@class='result-price']")))
  for i,j in zip(items, prices):
      print(i.text + j.text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Got some error in importing sir. Like  `unable to import selenium.webdriver.support`

Comment: @Vince `import` should work irrespective of the underlying code block. Restart your _IDE_. If the error still persists you may have to reinstall _selenium_.