# why do i keep receiving NoSuchElementException for which im required to update xpath from website although xpath remains unchanged

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating the process of downloading data from snapchat, and I've written a code that works, but every now and then (notably when i change the username and password details), when it comes to the step where the type of data to download is selected (up to 9 buttons/labels are clicked to check/uncheck what i want downloaded) the script stops working and gives me the `NoSuchElementException`

Here is the shortened snippet of code that is giving me problems, and [here is the full version with the preceding code](https://pastebin.com/UKDG0fcE):

```
select_data_xpath = {
    'user': '/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[1]/div[5]/div/div[3]/label',
    'chat': '/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/section[1]/div[6]/div/div[3]/label',
    'support': '/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/section[1]/div[9]/div/div[3]/label',
    'other': '/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/section[1]/div[12]/div/div[3]/label'
}


def click_data_buttons(dictionary):
    for value in dictionary.values():
        data_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value)
        data_button.click()


click_data_buttons(select_data_xpath)
```

Here is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\T.py", line 62, in <module>
    click_data_buttons(select_data_xpath)
  File "C:\Users\m\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\T.py", line 58, in click_data_buttons
    data_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\m\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\m\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\m\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/section[1]/div[6]/div/div[3]/label; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:189:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:507:5
dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:132:16
```

to sort this, I'm required to replace the existing `xpaths` by copying and pasting the xpaths from the website again, and then it works fine. but the weird thing is, the new xpaths that i replace the old ones with are exactly the same, theres literally no difference in character.

i tried cutting and pasting the `xpaths` from the script back into the script, and that doesnt work, so for the code to stop giving me the error, i need to actually copy the xpath from the website itself.

All the other buttons in the script work fine, its just this set of buttons/labels that stop working every now and then. it just makes no sense to me, because its not like the xpath has changed at all.

Why is this happening and what can i do to prevent it?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the xpath that you're copying in is exactly the same as what was there already? Really really sure? Not just "it looks identical when I skim it by eye"

Comment: yeah its tedious because youre using absolute xpaths. check relative xpaths instead

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps I try to follow when I face some XPath issue:

- Use relative XPath instead of Absolute XPath (as mentioned by [Rolandas Ulevicius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12175652/rolandas-ulevicius)) [(details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183353/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-and-relative-xpaths-which-is-preferred)
- Try monitoring the network requests and see if the element you are trying to access is dynamically loaded or not. Sometimes, pages use API calls via JS scripts to change innerHTML properties of DOM elements. Maybe along the path of the element you want to find, somewhere something is changing dynamically leading to changed absolute XPath.