# Robot framework is not able to fetch the locator, i tried copying the xpath ,still i am getting this "unable to find the locator" error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, pycharm, robotframework, relative-locators

[This is the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDCjz.png)

I am trying to automate an application using Robot framework , selenium in PyCharm tool.

I tried keyword definition to click on the side bar entity called "GCC Intelligence", I am getting below error:

```
Element with locator '/html/body/div[1]/aside/section/ul/li[3]/a' not found.
```

Comment: That looks like an autogenerated selector that depends heavily on the HTML. Selenium sees a different HTML, different browser version even if same browser. https://devhints.io/xpath, for example, has several suggestions on making xpaths based on href attribute. None of the suggestions depend on body structure

Comment: Also, you could check whether the element is inside the `IFRAME` tag, which makes it invisible for Selenium if another iframe is selected.  In this case, the keyword [Select Frame](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame) could be handy

Answer (score 1):

Absolute XPath expressions are not reliable. Try to use relative XPaths instead.

Change your XPath expression to:

```
//a[@href='/gvv-intelligence-platform']
```

Or this:

```
//span[text()='GCC Intelligence']
```

Refer this answer to know more about absolute and relative XPaths

- [What is the difference between absolute and relative xpaths? Which is preferred in Selenium automation testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183353/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-and-relative-xpaths-which-is-preferred)