# How do I access href inside div, class and class selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
    <div>
             <p class="otp-timer resend_otp_message" style="display: none;">Didn’t receive an OTP? <br> Resend OTP in <span id="resendcountdown">0:00</span> seconds
         </p>
             <p class="resend_button" style="display: block; padding-top: 24px;">Didn’t receive an OTP? <br>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)">Resend OTP</a>
          </p>
              <p class="hidden-phone back-otp-arrow" style="margin-left: 50%; margin-top: -60px; cursor: pointer;">Modify Number</p>
              <p class="otp_msg_failed" style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 25px; color: red; margin-bottom: 5px;">Please Enter Correct OTP</p>
              <button type="submit" class="login-button verify_code" id="otp-verify-btn-box">Verify</button>
    </div>
```

Error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: /html/body/div[7]/main/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/p[2]/a (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

have tried many methods

1. Tried below code,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/main/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/p[2]/a"))).click();
```

2. have tried link text - directly pointing to "Resend OTP"
3. tried passing the javascript:void(0) and text - resend otp in xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute XPath expressions are not reliable. Try to use relative XPaths instead.

Change your XPath expression to:

```
//a[text()='Resend OTP']
```

Refer this answer to know more about absolute and relative XPaths

- [What is the difference between absolute and relative xpaths? Which is preferred in Selenium automation testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183353/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-and-relative-xpaths-which-is-preferred)